# Groovy Postbuild in Jenkins, parsing the log for strings and counting them

Tags: java, string, groovy, jenkins, count

I am new to Groovy and am trying to set up a postbuild in Jenkins that allows me to count strings and determine if the build succeeded by how many the count returns at the end.

Here is my example code :

```
class Main {

  def manager = binding.getVariable("manager")
  def log = manager.build.logFile.text
  def list = log
  def JobCount = list.count {it.startsWith("====") && it.contains("COMPLETE")}
  if (JobCount == 7) {
      manager.listener.logger.println("All Jobs Completed Successfully")
  } else {
      manager.addWarningBadge("Not All Jobs Have Completed Successfully")
      manager.buildUnstable()  
  }
}
```

I am looking for a specific string that gets printed to the console when the test has completed successfully. The string is "====JOB COMPLETE====" and I should have 7 instances of this string if all 7 tests passed correctly.

Currently when I run this code I get the following error :

```
Script1.groovy: 6: unexpected token: if @ line 6, column 5.
   if (JobCount == 7)
   ^
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`manager.build.logFile.text` returns the whole file text as String.

What you need is `readLines()`:

```
def list = manager.build.logFile.readLines()
def JobCount = list.count {it.startsWith("====") && it.contains("COMPLETE")}
```

and of course as mentioned below, the Jenkins Groovy Postbuild plugin runs Groovy scripts, so you will have get rid of the enclosing class declaration (`Main`)

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You have statements directly inside your class, without being in a method, which is not allowed in Java/Groovy. Since this is Groovy, you can run this as a script without the class at all, or put the offending code (the `if` statement) inside a method and call the method.

Comment: I moved everything out of the class as you had mentioned. I was not aware that was unnecessary, thanks for that. Now when I run this without the main class, I get an error, that says no signature of method : java.lang.string.count() is applicable for argument types: (Script1$_run_closure1) values: [Script1$_run_closure1@77a3b365]

Comment: After that it says Possible solutions: count(java.lang.CharSequence), count(java.lang.String), toSet(), toSet(), toURL(), toURL()

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're missing a closing }

```
def JobCount = list.count {it.startsWith("====") && it.contains("COMPLETE")}
```

Comment: Ah, good catch. I added this } back in where it should be and now get the error:                                                                                     Script1.groovy: 6: unexpected token: if @ line 6, column 5.
if (JobCount == 7) {
^

Comment: arrow is under the if in the first if statement

Comment: I removed that last bracket when I fixed the one you commented before.