# How can Groovy Postbuild check the log message of a previous post-build action

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I want to access the log of another post-build action, which runs right before the groovy postbuild.

The console output looks like this:

```
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.48
Code Metrics Report path: **/*.Metrics.xml
Code Metrics Report Not Found.
Build step 'Record VS Code Metrics PowerTool Report' changed build result to UNSTABLE
```

I cannot use `manager.logContains()` because the output was generated by another post-build action.

I can set the build status to SUCCESS, but I want to do it only if the post-build action logged `Build step 'Record VS Code Metrics PowerTool Report' changed build result to UNSTABLE`

```
if (manager.build.result == hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE 
        && ???.contains("Build step 'Record VS Code Metrics PowerTool Report' changed build result to UNSTABLE") {
  manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
}
```

Comment: Another approach without groovy is to download the console logs e.g. wget http://<jenkins>:8080/job/<job_name>/<job_id>/consoleText and then using regex grep this output and take further decisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `manager.build.logFile.readLines()`.

For example,

```java
if (manager.build.result == hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE

        && manager.build.logFile.readLines().contains("Build step 'Record VS Code Metrics PowerTool Report' changed build result to UNSTABLE") {

    manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS

}
```

See [Oni Dar's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32082714/6605482) for an example.