# How to run a second job in Jenkins if after the first job we got a specific value in console output

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm new to Jenkins and have the follwing task.  I'm trying to run a job when a condition is met, this condition will come from the console log.

There is a method, in a first job, that outputs to console "Yes" or "No". I need to parse this console output, get the value and if it is "Yes", I want to start the second job, if "No", don't start it.

I've tried to search for jenkins plugins but there is nothing that fits my task or I just didn't find it.

Can anyone give me advice or solutions:

1. To parse console output and get my param "Yes" or "No"
2. To run the second job if param is "Yes"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a job using the [Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)

> Remote API can be used to do things like these:
>
> 1. retrieve information from Jenkins for programmatic consumption.
> 2. trigger a new build
> 3. create/copy jobs

You could have a groovy step in your first job which follows [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082205/groovy-postbuild-in-jenkins-parsing-the-log-for-strings-and-counting-them) to trigger a job on your condition

```
def list = manager.build.logFile.readLines()
def JobCount = list.count {it.startsWith("====") && it.contains("COMPLETE")}
```

And to [call an end point in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692515/groovy-built-in-rest-http-client) this is all you need

```
def html = "http://google.com".toURL().text
```